# CFOUTPUT with query from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Here is my code that I am working with -

```
<CFOUTPUT>

<CFQUERY NAME="getParser" DATASOURCE="LibraryDB" DBTYPE="ODBC">
select name
from parser_acronym 
where init = '#source#'
</CFQUERY>


<CFQUERY NAME="getUAcode" DATASOURCE="LibraryDB" DBTYPE="ODBC"> 
SELECT name FROM useragent 
WHERE Logs.csuseragent contains '#%useragent.string%#' </CFQUERY>
</CFQUERY>

<CFSET src = "#getParser.name#">
<CFSET ua = "#getUAcode.name#">

<CFIF (DailyCount MOD 2) EQ 0>
<CFSET via = '<td style="background-color: DBEFB6;">#src#<br><font color="blue">#ua#</font></td>'>
<CFELSE>
<CFSET via = '<td>#src#<br><font color="blue">#ua#</font></td>'>
</CFIF>
</CFOUTPUT>
```

I am pulling data from a table using the getParser query. This is displaying it as #src# - this works correctly.

Now, I need to add some more information and this will display in the #ua# (useragent) field. I need this query to understand that when my logs table contains the 'string' from the useragent table that it will display the name that coincides with that in the csuseragent table. So I am pulling a query from two tables and the WHERE must be a 'contains'. Is this even possible?

Here are my table examples -

Useragent Table -

**NAME**    |   **STRING**

IE      |   msie
FFox    |   firefox
 
iPad    |   ipad

Logs table has a csuseragent is the usual UA string that is filled with a whole lot of text but has defining words in it to tell us what the user is browsing on-

**CSUSERAGENT**
etcetc_msie
etcetc_firefox
etcetc_ipad
etcetc_msie
etcetc_msie

Comment: Is it just me, or does anyone else see a bunch of question marks instead of sql for the 2nd query.

Comment: I am sorry @DanBracuk - I put them in there as that is what I needed help on... :/ I was unsure how to highlight that that was the area in question :( Sorry!

Comment: Edit your post and put the sql in the 2nd query.  Your comment will make it clear that this is the area causing you difficulty.

Comment: Thank you @DanBracuk - I have just edited it now. :)

Comment: I have a couple of issues with the getUAcode query that you just shared. First, the pound and percent signs are out of order.  You have `WHERE Logs.csuseragent contains '#%useragent.string%#'` but it should be `WHERE Logs.csuseragent contains '%#useragent.string#%'` (percent signs outside of the pound signs).  However, I also believe that the percent signs are only used as wildcard characters with the `LIKE` operator in SQL.  I'm not sure they work with `CONTAINS`. You could change your query to use `WHERE Logs.csuseragent like '%#useragent.string#%'` instead. Should also use `<cfqueryparam>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a little trouble following along, but I think this is what you want:

```
<cfquery name="getUACode">
    SELECT UA.name AS UA, PA.name AS src
    FROM parser_acronym PA
    LEFT JOIN Useragent UA ON PA.name LIKE '%' + UA.name + '%'
    WHERE PA.init = <cfqueryparam value="#source#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
    <cfif NOT dailycount MOD 2>
        <cfset via = '<td class="myBgColor">#src#<br><span class="blueColor">#ua#</span></td>'>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset via = '<td>#src#<br><span class="blueColor">#ua#</span></td>'>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I didn't know if I could've used a 2nd query something like `<CFQUERY NAME="getUAcode" DATASOURCE="LibraryDB" DBTYPE="ODBC">
SELECT name
FROM useragent
WHERE Logs.csuseragent contains '#%useragent.string%#'
</CFQUERY>`

Comment: In that case you would have to join your logs table. In your example SQL has no idea what `Logs` is. You could however bring in the first result by `<cfqueryparam value="#getParser.name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">` or however else you need. I'm not really finding a log table in your examples.

Comment: @Jen - That is *very* different than what Chris posted. Take a look at his example again. He is suggesting you do a `join` between your two database tables. (If you are unfamiliar with joins, you should review [a sql tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_join.asp) first). Obviously you need to adjust his example and plug in your *actual* table and column names.

Comment: Thank you @leigh and @christierney - I am checking out `join` now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a start to your answer.  Since you didnt define the query for your getUA query, i was a little unsure of what your criteria and variables are and where they come from.

In general, I dont understand the variable UA.

```
<CFQUERY NAME="getParser" DATASOURCE="LibraryDB" DBTYPE="ODBC">
select name
from parser_acronym 
where init = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#source#">
</CFQUERY>

<CFQUERY NAME="getUAcode" DATASOURCE="LibraryDB" DBTYPE="ODBC"> 
SELECT name 
FROM useragent 
WHERE Logs.csuseragent like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#useragent.string#%#">
</CFQUERY>    

<CFSET src = "#getParser.name#">
<CFSET ua = "#getUAcode.name#">


<CFOUTPUT>
    <CFIF (DailyCount MOD 2) EQ 0>
        <CFSET via = '<td style="background-color: DBEFB6;">#src#<br><font color="blue">#ua#</font></td>'>
    <CFELSE>
        <CFSET via = '<td>#src#<br><font color="blue">#getUacode(ua)#</font></td>'>
    </CFIF>
</CFOUTPUT>
```

Comment: Hi Steve - see I didn't know if I could've used a 2nd query something like `<CFQUERY NAME="getUAcode" DATASOURCE="LibraryDB" DBTYPE="ODBC">
SELECT name
FROM useragent
WHERE Logs.csuseragent contains '#%useragent.string%#'
</CFQUERY>`

Comment: Woot! I think it is nearly there - the only error coming up now is `Element STRING is undefined in USERAGENT` so I am trying to fix it. I was just very unsure about how to word the query - this has been a great help @steve ! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: :( Still cannot get it to work. I've checked the debugger and it is crashing at our getUAcode query. I'll try doing some more googling. Thanks for you help. :)

Comment: @Jen since I am not familiar with your application, a few things stick out as wierd, for example "from useragent where logs.csuseragent".. I don't get the part about "logs."  THat would indicate your table, but you only reference useragent as your table in your from statement so where useragent.csuseragent would be the correct statement.  I also guess this is a partial snippet of code, because I have no idea where your useragent.string comes into play based on what you posted.

Comment: Oh sorry - I cannot post the whole code as it is hundreds and hundreds of lines but first I am pulling the logs table. Then within this we have other queries to fill a table of data (usage stats) We want to put in the useragent string (a field that we get from the logs table) BUT it is a whole line of text. In that line though is text that determines the browser. eg. MSIE for IE. It is making that work with the existing code. To get it working outside of this page I had something like this (and it works... haven't included all the useragents etc)-

Comment: `<cfquery name="getSource" DATASOURCE="LibraryDB" DBTYPE="ODBC">
    SELECT *
    FROM Logs
    WHERE csuseragent like '%iphone%' OR csuseragent like '%opera%' OR csuseragent like '%firefox%'
    ORDER by date desc, csusername 
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
<cfloop query="getSource">
<CFIF '#getSource.csuseragent#' contains "blackberry">Blackberry</CFIF> 
<CFIF '#getSource.csuseragent#' contains "iphone">iPhone</CFIF>
<CFIF '#getSource.csuseragent#' contains "ipad">iPad</CFIF> 
etc
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>`